# NativeBase's "Icon and Expanded Icon Style" not showing

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**I am new in this... I missed something while installation**

*My question is why icons are not showing with the simple code copy&past from nativebase.io
The build is successful with all function but only things are*

**1. top left "icon with Header content st.."  text is not showing
2. right bottom dropdown for open and closing icons are not showing that look like missing images or icons from the path**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.3",
    "native-base": "^2.13.12",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.3.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.3.3"
  },
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skPL2.png)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Header, Content, Accordion } from "native-base";
const dataArray = [
  { title: "First Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
  { title: "Second Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
  { title: "Third Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" }
];
export default class AccordionHeaderContentStyleExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content padder>
          <Accordion
            dataArray={dataArray}
            headerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#b7daf8" }}
            contentStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#ddecf8" }}
          />
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Can you try to add this code to `app/build.gradle` and uninstall the app from phone and reinstall again

    apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

[image]

thank now it's working but only the bottom icons + & - ( top icon and text are not)